# open games on ubuntu from python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

i am building a python script that can do certain tasks. I am now focusing on opening and application from the script i used subprocess.call and os.startfile but nothing helped and returned error the code is-

```
import os
while True:
message=raw_input("Enter your message >> ")
if message=="quit":
    exit()
elif message=="bye":
    exit()
elif message=="bye bye":
    exit()
elif message=="good bye":
    exit()
elif message=="see u":
    print "Okay then :)"
    exit()
elif message=="open games":
    print "on to that"
    os.start(gnome-mines)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where is error code and error message?

Comment: Also in code, you have written "os.start". It should be "os.startfile"

Comment: the error code is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testaiml.py", line 30, in <module>
    os.startfile( "/usr/games/gnome-mines")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'startfile' @DineshPundkar

Comment: Sorry I missed earlier. os.startfile only available with WIndows.

Comment: Check this - https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile

Comment: Use os.system instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.startfile` is only available with **Windows**.
Please [check here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile) !!!

Instead of `os.startfile`, use `os.system`.

Make sure file and user has execution permissions.

Answer (score 0):

you have to enter the complete path of the file to be opened

```
elif message=="open games":
print "on to that"
os.system("/usr/games/gnome-mines")
```